# adding pushpins on map in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Unable to add pushpins to the map in windows phone 8.1 :

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="RestoMap" MapServiceToken="" Height="550" Margin="0,60,0,0" Width="380">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapPins">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Maps:MapElement >

                    </Maps:MapElement>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:MapControl>
```

Code : the coordinates are retrieved correctly

```
 foreach (var item in AllResto)
    {
         String id = item.id;
         Double latitude = item.latitude;
         Double longitude = item.longitude;
         AllSavedPins.Add(new Data(id, latitude, longitude));
    }
    MapPins.ItemsSource = this.AllSavedPins;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do::

```
foreach(var pin in AllSavedPins)
{
    RestoMap.Children.Add(pin);
}
```

Comment: What is the data class? is that a custom class you have created? I would say AllSavedPins should be a List of `PushPins` [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh850857.aspx) also [see here for another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222368/how-do-i-add-a-pushpin-to-a-windows-phone-8-1-map-control)

Comment: data class is a custom class, maybe the error from the XAML

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use XAML for adding pushpins to maps as the binding in WP8.1 maps just isn't up to scratch and can get very complicated. I would create a pushpin for each location you would like to add and then add them as children as I have shown. To remove them use `RestoMap.Children.Clear()`