# WP 8.1 MapControl How add custom pushpin and programmatically add ItemSource?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How add to my map control custom pushpin?
I need in my pin:
TextBlock and Button

I try something like this:

```
<Maps:MapControl Grid.Row="2"
                    x:Name="MapControl"
                    MapServiceToken=""
                    Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                <Maps:MapItemsControl >
                    <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Height="25" Text="{Binding Where}" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" />
                                <Button Content="MyButton" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl>
            </Maps:MapControl>
```

But how can I add DataSource or ItemsSource to my MapItemsControl?
I need do this in code behind.

My model:

```
public class PinModel
    {
        public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
        public string Where { get; set; }
    }
```

And how do something like this:

```
List<PinModel> pins = new List<PinModel>();
MapControl.DataSource = pins?????(how can I do this?)
```

And get pins on my map.

Using Windows Phone 8.1

```
Maps:MapControl
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i add a pushpin to a Windows Phone 8.1 Map Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222368/how-do-i-add-a-pushpin-to-a-windows-phone-8-1-map-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a great tutorial for this up on Shawn Kendrot his blow here : http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/08/13/Bind-a-collection-of-items-to-the-Windows-Phone-MapControl.aspx

It has an example project link at the bottom, that should get you sorted out.